# google visualization bar chart stacking two bars

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a google visualization bar chart [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/gu32eb6a/) where the data format is as given below.

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);
```

How to make expenses and profits bar stacked where as sales is a separate bar?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the Google Charts API doesn't have this in built feature, but with some remodeling of the DataTable and Chart Options you can still achieve this.

**My Solution**

The Stacked Bar should contain values of only Expenses and Profit, to avoid a Stacked bar with Sales the value in the data column for Sales is represented as zero. A separate Sales bar is created by having a similar data row, but with the value of Sales present, and the rest zero. The Date data type needs to be specified in order to group all bar charts with the same date, if this isn't implemented, then there will be a gap between each bar chart with the same year.
 More information on Date representation of Columns is available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation).

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [ {label: 'Year', id: 'year', type: 'date'},
      {label: 'Sales', id: 'Sales', type: 'number'}, 
      {label: 'Expenses', id: 'Expenses', type: 'number'},
      {label: 'Profit', id: 'Profit', type: 'number'}],
      [{v:new Date('2014'), f:'2014'}, 0, 400, 200],
      [{v:new Date('2014'), f:'2014'}, 1000, 0, 0],
      [{v:new Date('2015'), f:'2015'}, 0, 460, 250],
      [{v:new Date('2015'), f:'2015'}, 1170, 0, 0],
      [{v:new Date('2016'), f:'2016'}, 0, 1120, 300],
      [{v:new Date('2016'), f:'2016'}, 600, 0, 0],
      [{v:new Date('2017'), f:'2017'}, 0, 540, 350],
      [{v:new Date('2017'), f:'2017'}, 1030, 0, 0]
    ]);
```

To achieve the stacked bar, the google charts configuration option `isStacked: true` is used. To avoid the vertical axis acting like a timeline with months and days, the vertical axis is formatted to display the Year using `vAxis: {format: 'yyyy'}`. More information on formatting is available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#formatting-axis-gridline-and-tick-labels). To avoid spacing between different Year Bars, the feature  `bar: {groupWidth: '90%'}` is used.

```
var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
      hAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      vAxis: {
        format: 'yyyy'
      },
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3'],
      isStacked: true,
      bar: {groupWidth: '90%'}
    };
```